# Eclipse Plugin: Editor for a file type with some simple elements

Tags: eclipse, plugins, editor, emf, rich-client-platform

I want to create a plugin for Eclipse that allows me to edit a file in a graphical way. Parsing and saving the file is no problem, but I can't seem to figure out the simplest way of designing an editor in Eclipse. I guess this must be super easy, but I can only find complex examples when googling, and no simple solution for quickly sticking together a GUI as an editor (I don't want to define an entire EMF model etc. for this simple task).

The editor should only have a few simple lists and add and delete button to edit these lists. In should open when I double click the file with the appropriate file ending.

Questions:

In RCP4 required for this or just a normal editor plugin?

In started of with the normal editor plugin generated by the Wizard that provides a XMLEditor. What is the recommend way for adding these simple model editing elements (lists)?

Comment: You are probably talking about something based on `FormEditor` but I won't call that simple.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a similar editor using Window Builder, Forms, and EMF JFace data bindings.

It is not that complex, but I wouldn't call it simple either. Or, put it differently - it is all simple once you know how it works, but you'll have to invest some time in gaining that knowledge.

Some links which should help you get started:

- https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/
- http://blog.vogella.com/2016/06/14/helping-windowbuilder/ - WindowBuilder for Neon
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataBindingEMF/article.html
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataBinding/article.html
- https://tomsondev.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/emf-databinding.pdf
- https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding
- https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html